# SAT Writing Question

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, past-tense, writing

> **Upon considering** the facts of the case; he quickly made a decision and sent the police.

- A. When he considered
- B. Considering
- C. Upon Considering
- D. When
  Considering

Hello everyone, I just had a question about grammar. I picked **choice A** and got the correct answer, but I wans't too confident about why I should eliminate the others.

Just to give my insight into this: I picked A because I thought that there must be past tense. But I can't strongly make a choice to eliminate them.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks for your time.

Comment: D is the only option I would reject outright.  Otherwise the choice depends in the context and circumstances.

Comment: Why have you written answer "C" in the blank space, if it is "wrong"? Correct capitalization is an important feature in English written tests and exams, so please check whether answers C and D are copied correctly.

Comment: Your question cannot be an SAT question. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: A semicolon joins independent clauses.

Answer (score 0):

*A* matches the sentence better than *B* or *D* because *A* uses the past tense, as you correctly point out. Although the intent of *B* can still be understood in the context of the full sentence, *A* is clearer.

*C* and *D* present *Considering* with a capital *C* when it should be in lower case. If not for capitalization, *C* would obviously be the best match.